# How to return user details from the Active Directory using PrincipalContext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a new action method that when called it will return all the Active Directory usernames. The asp.net mvc application and Active Directory are within the same domain (and currently inside the same development machine).

So I have defined the following action method:-

```
public ViewResult Details()
        {
 var c = repository.GetUserDetails3();
return View("Details2",c); }
```

and the following repository method:-

```
public DirectoryEntry GetUserDetails3()
{   
     DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();

     using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "WIN-SPDEV.com"))
     {
         using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
         {
             foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
             {
                 de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry; 
             }
         }
     }
     return de; 
}
```

and the following model class:-

```
public class DirectoryUser
    {public Nullable<Guid> Guid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
}}
```

and on the view I have:-

```
@model IEnumerable<TMS.Models.DirectoryUser>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details2";
}

<h2>Details2</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Guid)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Username)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Guid)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)
        </td>
```

but when I call the action method I got the following error:-

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type
>
> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TMS.Models.DirectoryUser]'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you are mixing the new `PrincipalContext` with the old `DirectoryEntry` stuff. Doesn't make any sense.....

Also - you're searching for **all** users, but in the end, you're returning only a single `DirectoryEntry` - why?!?

If you're using the new `PrincipalContext` - then use the `UserPrincipal` - it contains nice and easy to use properties about the user - much easier to use and work with than the old `DirectoryEntry` stuf....

```
public List<UserPrincipal> GetAllUsersDetails()
{   
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "WIN-SPDEV.com"))
    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
    {
       var searchResults = searcher.FindAll();

       List<UserPrincipal> results = new List<UserPrincipal>();

       foreach(Principal p in searchResults)
       {
           results.Add(p as UserPrincipal);
       }
    }
}
```

The `UserPrincipal` class has really nice properties like `GivenName` (first name), `Surname` and so forth - easy to use, strongly-typed properties. Use them!

Read all about those new classes and how to use them here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the reply it worked fine . but the problem is that if i retrieve the User.Identity.Name and assign it to a Created-by field , then the value will be something such as domainname\user1 . while when using Principle class none of its method; UserPrincipal, Name, DisplayName will return such a values. the Principle.userPrinciple will return user1@domainname.local. so this will make confusion on my system ?

Comment: @johnG: why should a `CreatedBy = domain\JohnG` cause *confusion* in your system? It records **exactly** who created that piece of data in your system ... isnt' that what you want??

Comment: Yes. i am working on an intranet application with windows authentication on. i have the following "objectname.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name". which will automatically be stored as Domainname\Username. while using the above Principle class i will get users as "username@dmainname.local".so i will have different strings representing the same user. so how i can overcome this conflict?

Comment: @johnG: well, then just keep using `User.Identity.Name` for your `CreatedBy` column, and grab other information from the `UserPrincipal` (like first name, last name, SAM Account Name, and whatever else you need...)

Comment: but what is i want to compare both values , for example where CreatedBy = UserGroup.username . then this will always return false as the same user will have different format?